# select * through dblink

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, dblink

I have some trouble when trying to update a table by looping cursor which select from source table through dblink.

I have two database DB1, DB2.

They are two different database instance.
And I am using this following statement in DB1:

```
CURSOR TestCursor IS
    SELECT  a.*, 'A' TEST_COL_A, 'B' TEST_COL_B
    FROM rpt.SOURCE@DB2  a;
BEGIN
    For C1 in TestCursor loop
        INSERT into  RPT.TARGET 
        (

           /*The company_name and cust_id are select from SOURCE table from DB2*/  
           COMPANY_NAME, CUST_ID, TEST_COL_A, TEST_COL_B

        ) 
        values
        (  
           C1.COMPANY_NAME, C1.CUST_ID, C1.TEST_COL_A , C1.TEST_COL_B
        ) ;

    End loop;

    /*Some code...*/

End
```

Everything works fine until I add a column "NEW_COL" to SOURCE table@DB2

The insert data got the wrong value.

The value of TEST_COL_A , as I expect, should be 'A'.

However, it contains the value of NEW_COL which i add at SOURCE table.

And the value of TEST_COL_B contains 'A'.

Have anyone encounter the same issue?
It seems like oracle cache the table columns when it compile.
Is there any way to add a column to source table without recompile?

Comment: didn't you try to specify strict list of columns (a.COMPANY_NAME, a.CUST_ID) instead of a.* ?

Comment: What is you setting for [`REMOTE_DEPENDENCY_MODE`](http://psoug.org/reference/db_link.html)? It can be `SIGNATURE` or `TIMESTAMP`, each causing different problems ;-)  Also using `*` is not a good thing, try explicit column names as @heximal mentions.

Comment: @amep: `REMOTE_DEPENDENCY_MODE` only applies to remote procedures, not tables.

Comment: did u try using NOCACHE hint in your SQL?  Curious if cache is your problem(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_dependencies.htm#i1365):

> Oracle Database does not manage
>   dependencies among remote schema
>   objects other than
>   local-procedure-to-remote-procedure
>   dependencies.
>
> For example, assume that a local view
>   is created and defined by a query that
>   references a remote table. Also assume
>   that a local procedure includes a SQL
>   statement that references the same
>   remote table. Later, the definition of
>   the table is altered.
>
> Therefore, the local view and
>   procedure are never invalidated, even
>   if the view or procedure is used after
>   the table is altered, and even if the
>   view or procedure now returns errors
>   when used. In this case, the view or
>   procedure must be altered manually so
>   that errors are not returned. In such
>   cases, lack of dependency management
>   is preferable to unnecessary
>   recompilations of dependent objects.

In this case you aren't quite seeing errors, but the cause is the same. You also wouldn't have a problem if you used explicit column names instead of `*`, which is usually safer anyway. If you're using `*` you can't avoid recompiling (unless, I suppose, the `*` is the last item in the select list, in which case any extra columns on the end wouldn't cause a problem - as long as their names didn't clash).

Comment: Thanks for your help! These are some existing code in our DB, and now  I think it's time to change the code. :p

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a single set processing insert statement in DB1 rather than a row at a time cursor for loop for the insert, for example:

```
INSERT into  RPT.TARGET 
select COMPANY_NAME, CUST_ID, 'A' TEST_COL_A, 'B' TEST_COL_B
FROM rpt.SOURCE@DB2
;
```

***Rationale:***

1. Set processing will almost always out perform Row-at-a-time
   processing [which is really slow-at-a-time processing].
2. Set processing the insert is a scalable solution. If the application will need to scale to tens of thousands of rows or millions of rows, the row-at-a-time solution will not likely scale.
3. Also, using the `select *` construct is dangerous for the reason you
   encountered [and other similar reasons].